# D if or/and statement like python

Tags: d

Do D have any way of expressing and/or in an if statement?

```
if (1 > 2 or 3 < 5 and 1 == 1)
{
/* run code */
}
```

Like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or is `||` and and is `&&`, just like in C, C++, Java, C#, and other languages from that family:

```
if (1 > 2 || 3 < 5 && 1 == 1)
{
/* run code */
}
```

Comment: Though please add some parenthesis so priority is clear, not everyone has the priority of || and && memorized.